# JUnit Tests are failing in IntelliJ with Error | MockitoException : Mockito cannot mock this class: classaerospike.core.AerospikeTemplate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, mockito, aerospike

**Below is the full stack trace of the exception :**

Test ignored.

**org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.springframework.data.aerospike.core.AerospikeTemplate.
Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.**

> Java               : 1.8 JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation JVM
> vendor version : 25.333-b02 JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM)
> 64-Bit Server VM JVM version        : 1.8.0_333-b02 JVM info
> : mixed mode OS name            : Mac OS X OS version         : 12.6

```
Underlying exception : java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.withBefores(DefaultInternalRunner.java:39)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$LazyProjection$ForLoadedReturnType.resolve(TypeDescription.java:5689)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$LazyProjection.accept(TypeDescription.java:5330)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$TypeSubstituting.getReturnType(MethodDescription.java:1332)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.asSignatureToken(MethodDescription.java:704)
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.SignatureTokenMatcher.matches(SignatureTokenMatcher.java:30)
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.SignatureTokenMatcher.matches(SignatureTokenMatcher.java:11)
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher$Junction$Conjunction.matches(ElementMatcher.java:101)
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.FilterableList$AbstractBase.filter(FilterableList.java:96)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassImplementationTarget.invokeConstructor(SubclassImplementationTarget.java:59)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassImplementationTarget.invokeSuper(SubclassImplementationTarget.java:45)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.Implementation$Target$AbstractBase.invokeDominant(Implementation.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.SuperMethodCall$Appender.apply(SuperMethodCall.java:95)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:620)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:609)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:526)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:4170)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1633)
    at net.
```

**These tests execute fine when run via mvn clean install cmd.
I have tried all the solutions I could find online like upgrading Mockito to the latest version, updating bytebuddy version etc.**

Answer (score 2):

According to this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final), You need to add a text file to the project's src/test/resources/mockito-extensions directory named org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker and add a single line of text:

mock-maker-inline

Mockito checks the extensions directory for configuration files when it is loaded. This file enables the mocking of final methods and classes.

Comment: Tried, This didn't work for Mocking Aerospiketemplate class.